# How to implement Full text search with Lucene tool for Derby Database

Tags: derby

**Classpath for running the luceneSupport optional tool:-**

Before I run the luceneSupport optional tool, set the classpath
contains the following jar files:

- derby.jar
- derbyoptionaltools.jar
- core: The core Lucene machinery. For Lucene 4.5.0, this is
  lucene-core-4.5.0.jar.
- analyzers-common: The common Lucene analyzers. For Lucene 4.5.0, this is
  lucene-analyzers-common-4.5.0.jar.
- queryparser: The basic Lucene logic for query-parsing. For Lucene 4.5.0, this is
  lucene-queryparser-4.5.0.jar.

First all I have created a database and inserted some values..

```
connect 'jdbc:derby:musetitles;create=true';
create schema MUSE;
   set schema MUSE;



 create table titles (ID int generated always as identity, ISBN varchar(16),      PRINTISBN varchar(16), title varchar(1024), subtitle varchar(1024), author varchar(1024), series varchar(1024), publisher varchar(1024), collections varchar(128), collections2 varchar(128));



 insert into titles (ISBN, PRINTISBN, TITLE, SUBTITLE, AUTHOR, SERIES, PUBLISHER, COLLECTIONS, COLLECTIONS2) values ('9780823254859','9780823254811','American Dictators','Reading Rousseau through Fanon','Jane Anna Gordon teaches Political Science and African-American Studies at the University of Connecticut at Storrs. ','Just Ideas','Fordham University Press','2014 Complete','2014 Philosophy and Religion');



insert into titles (ISBN, PRINTISBN, TITLE, SUBTITLE, AUTHOR, SERIES, PUBLISHER, COLLECTIONS, COLLECTIONS2) values ('9780823255313','9780823255283','Shaping the Future of African American Film','','Kelly A. Parker is Professor of Philosophy, Environmental Studies, & Liberal Studies at Grand Valley State University.','American Philosophy','Fordham University Press','2014 Complete','2014 Philosophy and Religion');



 insert into titles (ISBN, PRINTISBN, TITLE, SUBTITLE, AUTHOR, SERIES, PUBLISHER, COLLECTIONS, COLLECTIONS2) values ('9780826353771','9780826353764','Buen Gusto and Classicism in the Visual Cultures of Latin America, 1780-1910','','Paul B. Niell','','University of New Mexico Press','2014 Complete','2014 History');



 insert into titles (ISBN, PRINTISBN, TITLE, SUBTITLE, AUTHOR, SERIES, PUBLISHER, COLLECTIONS, COLLECTIONS2) values ('9780813563749','9780813563732','Treating AIDS','Politics of Difference, Paradox of Prevention','Thurka Sangaramoorthy','','Rutgers University Press','2014 Complete','2014 Political Science and Policy Studies');



 insert into titles (ISBN, PRINTISBN, TITLE, SUBTITLE, AUTHOR, SERIES, PUBLISHER, COLLECTIONS, COLLECTIONS2) values ('9780870717215','9780870717208','Accomplishing NAGPRA','Perspectives on the Intent, Impact, and Future of the Native American Graves Protection and Repatriation Act','Edited by Sangita Chari and Jaime M. N. Lavallee','First Peoples: New Directions in Indigenous Studies','Oregon State University Press','2014 Complete','2014 Political Science and Policy Studies');

 ALTER TABLE "MUSE"."TITLES" ALTER COLUMN "ID" NOT NULL;

 ALTER TABLE "MUSE"."TITLES" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_TITLES" PRIMARY KEY ("ID");



 call syscs_util.syscs_register_tool('luceneSupport',true);

 create procedure LuceneSupport.createIndex(schemaname varchar( 128 ),  tablename varchar( 128 ),textcolumn varchar( 128 ))parameter style java modifies sql data language java external name 'org.apache.derby.impl.optional.lucene.LuceneSupport.createIndex';

 CALL LUCENESUPPORT.CREATEINDEX( 'MUSE', 'TITLES', 'TITLE' ,null);

 SELECT * FROM TABLE( LUCENESUPPORT.LISTINDEXES() ) T;

 select * from table(MUSE.TITLES__TITLE('american -mexican',4, null)) t;
```

}

And I want to put full text search on multiple column in a same table while
I have tried many option but not success-ed. please help me out this problem.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Do you get an error? What is the exact output that it returned? What were you expecting to happen, and what actually happened instead?